# Error with .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to host a php based application with the following .htaccess values.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /easydeposit
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, I keep facing the following two errors,

```
[access_compat:error] [pid 25330:tid 27] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/abc/opt/apache/htdocs/xyz/system/
[access_compat:error] [pid 25330:tid 27]  AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/abc/opt/apache/htdocs/xyz/private/
[access_compat:error] [pid 25330:tid 27] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/abc/opt/apache/htdocs/xyz/application/
[authz_core:error] [pid 25330:tid 27]  AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/abc/opt/apache/htdocs/xyz/.htaccess
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 57):

If you have recently upgraded to a version of Apache greater than version 2.2, the authz_core error error might be coming from your httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf file in the `<Document>` tags. mod_authz_core was introduced in Apache 2.3 and changed the way that access control is declared.

So, for example, instead of the 2.2 way of configuring `<Directory>`...

```
    <Directory "C:/wamp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**Order** and **Allow** directives have been replaced with the **Require** directive:

```
    <Directory "C:/wamp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Sources 
http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/06/fun-with-wamp-server-and-apache-2-4-2/
         http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Is there really no way to handle it without intruding into Apache's config file? The problem is that you must have root's privileges to do it....

Answer (score 4):

This question/answer got me to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) for which I'm thankful, and the following was what solved it for me.

**Previous `.htaccess` file:**

```
# password protection allowing multiple resources
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile C:\path\to\.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user

# allow public access to the following resources
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path/to/public_files/.*)$" allow

# these lines must be updated

Order allow,deny
# Allowing an ip range:
Allow from 69.69.69
# Allowing another range:
Allow from 71.71.71

Satisfy any
```

This configuration was producing errors like:

> [Thu Dec 08 10:29:20.347782 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 2244:tid 15876] [client 93.93.93.93:49340] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/path/to/index.php

**updated for 2.4 configuration**

```
# 7 lines unchanged...shown again for clarification 
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile C:\path\to\.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path/to/public_files/.*)$" allow

# these are the changes replacing:

# Order allow,deny
# Allow from <range>
# Satisfy any

Require ip 69.69.69
Require ip 71.71.71
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this has anything to do with your htaccess file. The errors are thrown by [mod_access_compat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html), which provides the `Allow`, `Deny`, `Order`, and `Satisfy` directives. Somewhere, you probably have your allow's and deny's configured wrong. As for the .htaccess error at the end, it's from [mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html), so there may be something upstream that blocks access to .htaccess files outright.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your are allowed to override Options in your .htaccess file? check main apache config file for this

Comment: I have enabled override options in my httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
```

on many shared hosting the above code often the main problems

Comment: I tried it without the above code too, but does not seem to make any difference...

Answer (score 0):

And you are absolutely sure that the apache user (probably _www) has access to the directory (`/home/abc/opt/apache/htdocs/xyz/`)?

Comment: Yes absolutely. I made sure to change the user/group permissions for the directory

Answer (score 0):

Another example, rewrite from:

```
www.yoursite.com/script.php?product=123
```

to

```
www.yoursite.com/cat/product/123/
```

using

```
RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /script.php?$1=$2
```

http://w3webtutorial.blogspot.com/2013/11/htaccess-and-modrewrite-in-your-php.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was an .htaccess file in the wp-config folder that had these entries

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js)$">
Allow from all
</Files>
```

That caused icons in the interface to show up as squares.