# htaccess execute root/index for www.domain.de/some

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need to figure out how i can execute the index.php on webspace root.

I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Now i have a folder root/some/projects
In projects are some php logics.

I wana browse to www.domain.de/some and i get a Error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /some/ on this server.

Because in root/some is no php logic in. So i want that he executes the root/index.php coz there is a cms with the right content for www.domain.de/some and not the root/some/index.php

anyone have a solution?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your web server configuration, there is an [Options directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options), forbidding any access to directories, e.g.

```
Options -Indexes
```

In your .htaccess, you explicitly say don't rewrite for existing directories,
see [RewriteCond Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

> 4. You can perform various file attribute tests:
>
>    - '-**d**' (is **d**irectory)
>        Treats the *TestString* as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

If you remove this condition, the rule will work for directories too.

---

P.S., you don't need

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
```

because you already prevent the rule for existing files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: There is no "Options -Indexs" in my .htaccess.
If i remove "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" i have same forbidden error

Comment: The `Options -Indexes` need not be in your .htaccess file. It could be in your main or virtual host configuration or another .htaccess up in the filesystem.

Comment: Have you enabled rewrite, e.g. `RewriteEngine on`?

Comment: Yes i have enabled rewrite. I dont find a options-Indexes entity in all my files.

Comment: If you don't have any `Options` directive, the default takes over, which is [`Options FollowSymlinks`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options). Another reason could be `Order/Deny` directive or `Require`, if you use Apache 2.4. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/21551840/1741542 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13258044/1741542