# How do I fix this "You don't have permission to access / on this server." issue?

Tags: apache2

I have Apache 2.4.7. I also use ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

So I followed this:

http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4550/solved-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

and this:

[Error with .htaccess and mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140559/error-with-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

What it is telling me is that I should go into apache2.conf and add "Require all granted" for it to work.

This is what the inside of my apache2.conf file looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't figure out what exactly was causing the error but I ended up fixing it like this.

First delete the html folder, this won't workout doing this.

Second,

```
sudo apt-get purge -y apache2 mysql-server php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

then reinstall everything.

```
sudo apt-get install -y apache2 mysql-server php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

Then

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
sudo chown -R USERNAME /var/www
```

(Put username in username)